# Select a Range of Values in Another Column Based on Initial Selected Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to select an entire range of cells from a different column depending on the range of cells selected in the initial column.
For example, if A1:A5 is selected, I want the code to select E1:E5.  The initial range can vary depending on user input.

Just some background on the meaning of the code: I am comparing school districts' RX Plans, and I am able to select the appropriate school district (based on the user input again).  I just need to select the corresponding RX Plans which are in column E.

So far, I have been able to make something that when, for example, A6:A13 is selected, it automatically goes over and selects E6.  However, I need it to select the entirety of E6:E13 (or at least make those cells the active cells).

I know my issue lies with using `ActiveCell.Row`, as that obviously would select just one row.  I just don't know how to select an entire range.

Please note the entirety of the my code is not included as just the case with RX Plans is the only one relevant to this question.

```
Dim DistrictName As String

Dim DistrictOneRng As Range

Dim rALL As Range

Dim xDistrict As String

Dim ComparisonOption As String

xTitleId = "FindDistrictTool"

xDistrict = Application.InputBox("Enter Your District Name", xTitleId, Type:=2)

ComparisonOption = Application.InputBox("What do you want to compare: RX Plans, Metallic Levels, Number of Plans, Average AV", xTitleId, Type:=2)

Select Case ComparisonOption

    Case "RX Plans"

        With Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A130")

            Set DistrictOneRng = .Find(xDistrict, LookIn:=xlValues)
             If Not DistrictOneRng Is Nothing Then
                Set rALL = DistrictOneRng
                 DistrictName = DistrictOneRng.Address

                   Do
                     Set rALL = Union(rALL, DistrictOneRng)
                      Worksheets(1).Range(DistrictOneRng.Address).Activate
                      Set DistrictOneRng = .FindNext(DistrictOneRng)

                    Loop While Not DistrictOneRng Is Nothing And DistrictOneRng.Address <> DistrictName
            End If
            .Activate
            If Not rALL Is Nothing Then rALL.Select
       End With


       Range("E" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to set something up in your WORKSHEET code section (not your MODULE) and tie it to the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event.

Here's an example code that when `A1:A15` is selected, it will select `E1` to whatever row is listed as a number in cell **B1**. So if `B1` has a value of `5`, then the macro will select `E1:E5`.

I threw in additional combinations such as ANY cell in column A in the sample code. Hopefully you can extrapolate this out to do what you want to do with various if-statements of conditions.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'best to turn this off to avoid a loop
    '!! Note that if code errors before this gets back to being set to True
    'you will need to run code to set this to True somewhere for this event
    'to be be set to be triggered again.

    If Target.Address = Range("A1:A15").Address And IsNumeric(Me.Range("B1")) Then
        'Selects E1 to whatever row is in cell B1

        Range(Me.Range("E1"), Me.Range("E1").Offset(Me.Range("B1").Value, 0)).Select


    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        'This would automatically shift the selection from WHATEVER
        'is in column a to column E

        Intersect(Target.EntireRow, Me.Range("E:E")).Select

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
        'This will take the top cell in a selection in column E and then select
        'corresponding row in column E along with the additional rows specificed in cell B1

        Intersect(Target.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow, Me.Range("E:E")).Resize(Me.Range("B1").Value, 1).Select

    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True 'Turns events back on when done
End Sub
```

Comment: I have marked this answer as accepted since when I first put it in, it did work like it was supposed to.  However, after a few tries I started getting the Run-time error '424' Object required, and it would not execute anymore.  I tried for a solid hour and got it to work a few times again, and then it would just stop working.  Since it worked a few times, I'm assuming it's an error on my part rather than the code you gave me.  Any idea why this is happening?   The error is always on the line of code when I call the function by using `Worksheet_SelectionChange Target`

Comment: Update:  I put `Option Explicit` and it said `Target` wasn't defined, so I used `Dim Target As Range`.  Now the error is at the line `If Target.Address = Range("A1:A15").Address And IsNumeric(Me.Range("B1")) Then` with the error Run-Time error '91': Object variable or With variable not set.

Comment: Also, make sure you run somewhere, even in the immediate window... `Application.EnableEvents = True` to ensure your events get turned back on.